# Trouble converting Java code to Kotlin to implement an OnChangeListener

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I have this code to implement a listener for a **Range Bar library**:

```
rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftPinIndex,
                                          int rightPinIndex, String leftPinValue, String rightPinValue) {
        }

    });
```

Now I've tried to import it and change it to kotlin in the following ways:

```
rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(object: RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener {
        override fun onRangeChangeListener(rangeBar:RangeBar, leftPinIndex:Int,
                                  rightPinIndex:Int, leftPinValue:String, rightPinValue:String) {
            textView.text = "$leftPinIndex"
        }
    })
```

or

```
rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener { rangeBar, leftPinIndex, 
rightPinIndex, leftPinValue, rightPinValue -> 
textView.text = "$leftPinIndex" }
```

In both cases, the app crashes with the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.appyvet.materialrangebar.RangeBar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener> (com.appyvet.materialrangebar.RangeBar$OnRangeBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Your `rangebar` object is null

Comment: Your listener is fine. Read the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **`rangebar`** is **null**,

To avoid crash, use like this :

```
rangebar?.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(object: RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener {
    override fun onRangeChangeListener(rangeBar:RangeBar, leftPinIndex:Int, rightPinIndex:Int, leftPinValue:String, rightPinValue:String) {
        textView.text = "$leftPinIndex"
    }
})
```

*or*

```
rangebar?.setOnRangeBarChangeListener { rangeBar, leftPinIndex, rightPinIndex, leftPinValue, rightPinValue -> 
    textView.text = "$leftPinIndex" 
}
```